# App loading 600 static images locally, most optimal

Tags: ios

I have an app that showcases paintings, the number of paintings is about 600 ( so thats 600 png's ). The client wants me to include those images in the app build, so that they are always available to view even if the user if not online. Of course with every image comes some fields like description, painter, and price estimate, so this app will not stream anything and will have all of its data locally.

Anyway I am thinking of the best way to build this app, I thought of core data, and even encoding decoding, but since These images wil never change, I can put them in an images folder and on viewdidload just loop over contents of the folder and build my tableviewcells.

my question is :

1 : Is this a good architecture?

2 : I need to associate those images with the relevant description of them? whats the best way of doing this? If I jump into core data and create models I feel this would be an overkill.

Keep in mind that these images will never change, nor will the data be updated.

Thanks.

Comment: So you're just going to ask what to do for every step of building this app?

Comment: Add the pictures in a folder, if the application size with pictures is less than 50MB just bundle them , if the application larger than 50MB then add the pictures into some cloud like amazon and download them on demand or all of them when the application is installed

Comment: This is a bit too general of a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. As discussed in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17003348/1271826), I think that loading all of these images in the app has its disadvantages, given that you say that the app ends up being 300mb. If it is, indeed, going to be larger than 50mb, then I think you might want try to dissuade your customer from insisting that all of the images be included in the app, itself. I understand that you might not be able to convince them, but at least make sure they understand the implication of including all of these images (that it makes it harder to install the app and therefore, they may experience a lower adoption rate of their new app).
2. Storing the relevant description of the images in Core Data is a good approach. You could also use SQLite (e.g., via the [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) wrapper), but I'd really encourage you to just use Core Data unless you have some other considerations you haven't shared with us. But a lot of other traditional solutions for simplified persistent data (plists, `NSUserDefaults`, etc.) might not be appropriate for this many records. Core Data is great and really isn't that complicated. Sure, the first time you use Core Data, it takes a little getting used to, but it seems well suited for this amount of data.
3. You talk about "encoding and decoding" of the images, and you haven't described anything that would lead us to suggest that sort of process. What encoding/decoding are you contemplating? It's probably easier to just store the images in the local file system (in the bundle if included in the app, elsewhere [in the file system](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW12) if you're downloading the images on the fly).
4. You mention that you might have "`viewDidLoad` just loop over contents of the folder and build my tableviewcells". Perhaps I'm reading too much into this (in conjunction with your other question's comments about receiving memory warnings), but given that you are talking about keeping the images descriptions in Core Data, you don't need to be iterating through anything in `viewDidLoad`. Your [`UITableViewDataSource`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods will simply query the Core Data database and present the appropriate information. I don't see any need to be iterating through anything in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks, I am really trying to understand the pros and cons of any approach I take towards this.

Comment: For the second item in your answer, I think you missed the scenario of this app, I need to ship this app with some data preloaded already, wouldn't this warrant building a sqlite db ? or how do I do it through coredata?

Comment: @sleepy_ios No, I understood question but just presumed you'd ship app with db prepopulated. The process is similar on both CoreData and SQLite: 1. You write code for your app that populates the database if the database doesn't already exist. 2. You run this on the simulator. 3. You go to the simulator's folders on your computer and copy the populated database from there into your project. 4. You then modify your app to copy the database from the bundle to the apps' Documents folder if it doesn't already exist in the Documents folder.

Comment: Having done that, the app will now efficiently, on first run on a device, just copy the pre-populated database, otherwise it will just use the copy in Documents. See [CoreDataBooks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html) example for what the final solution looks like, copying db if not found.

Comment: Thanks Rob, IF I told you that I only have 800 rows ( or 800 objects ) would it make sense to just put them in a JSON file and incorporate that in the app and load them like that? since I really don't need a DB with all that comes with it?

Comment: @sleepy_ios You could do that if you want. I personally wouldn't, but to each his own. If you use this approach, make sure to check out your memory usage in Allocations tool and make sure you're not using too much memory. Make sure to test your app on the oldest physical device supported by your iOS versions (e.g. if iOS 5 or iOS 6, then test on iPhone 3GS, which only has 256mb of RAM). It just strikes me as a tad cavalier to load 800 objects into a `NSArray`, but if each object is small enough, you might get away with it.

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar kind of application some time ago. I used unique code names for the images and created a Core Data DB that would have one column associating the according line of data (description, author, ...) with the "code" name of the image (i.e., 2347.png).

My model was something simple like this:

```
NSNumber *imageCode // the number that you would use to associate to your images
NSString *name
NSString *author
NSString *description
```

I'm assuming that you know how to use Core Data.. if you don't, you can refer to this website: [Core Data on iOS 5 Tutorial: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started) .. it is really helpful!

Comment: SO on viewdidload, ( or whatever event ) you just load your coredata entries, and from there pickup images needed to associate with the entries? I assume performance was never slow for this?

Comment: To avoid performance issues (while filling the Cells with the images and data), it is good to employ some sort of lazy loading. In my case, there were more than 2000 images and it worked ok.